# What do you call a person that’s on break / temporarily retired?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single word for that. Please it’s very important.

Answer (score 1):

At universities, professors will go on [**sabbatical**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sabbatical):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **3** : a break or change from a normal routine (as of employment)

Typically, this lasts for a year, after which they return to their normal teaching duties.

---

In more general terms, you can also simply say that somebody is on [**leave**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave#h2):

> [Merriam Webster]
>
> **1 b** : authorized especially extended absence from duty or employment

---

However, there is no single word adjective for this that I know of. The closest expression is *off duty*, but that can be a regular (daily) occurrence rather than a longer absence.